# How to inject/update Version and other details in a binary (.net or unmanaged)?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, exe

I'm trying to develop a piece of Code (C++ or C#) through which I should be able to inject  File/Product version, company and copyright information into our binaries (.net and C++ based) before packing these into the installer.

Any help would be really appreciated?

Thanks

Comment: Have your configuration-management guys update a VERSIONINFO script that is `#include`d in the product resource script during the actual build. I strongly advise *against* mucking with a .NET binary post-build, as you're libel to hose the signature of the file and invalidate the component.

Comment: Yes, there is a Pre-Build procedure executing through PreBuildEvent, doing same. It either creates a .rc file or AssemblyInfo.cs or AssemblyInfo.cpp (in case of Managed C++).
But we want to separate Versioning procedure from Compiling step. Reason is some kind of requirement that same built binaries could be Re-Versioned without compiling the code (for which we have to execute a full compile procedure which might take 3-4 hours may be).

Comment: Actually, I've seen the use of a utility injecting the Version Resources into binaries directly in another organization. Unfortunately I can't ask them for the source code of their internal utility, so I'm trying to build my own doing same.

Comment: I guess I didn't say that clear enough, though I know its not what you want (which is why it is *here* rather than an answer). Where I work, a team dedicated just to producing *builds* is responsible for tagging source control, pulling  source, generating a version info script (its a substitution thing in reality), and kicking off the actual build. What comes out the other end is "the build" properly stamped. We don't, and will never, use msbuild or project settings for build-versioning. That is controlled by CM (aka the build guys). Just so you know what I was describing.

Answer (score 1):

For managed code you can use assembly attributes. Their values will be shown in file details, if you open it in explorer, and they also can be accessed from code.

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.7.35.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("QA")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("It's my app")]
```

Visual studio generates AssemblyInfo.cs file with these attributes for each project, so you can just update it.

Comment: Alex, this is what we are already doing. Please read my reply to @WhozCraig reply for the reason we want to inject/update version info directly into binaries.